# Implementing public API keys with microservices

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microservices, api-design

For most client applications and UI approaches JWTs seem to be a good way to carry tokens for an OAuth based approach. This allows decoupling of a User/Auth service and the services that are actually being accessed.

### Given this architecture

[image]

My question is: in the case of public APIs (ie Github or Slack) where a bearer key is generated with specific roles. How is that key authorized in a microservice architecture? Do those types of keys just require that the Auth service gets queried with every request?

Could an API gateway mitigate this? I would like to understand if a solution exists where there is minimal communication between services. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is solved using scopes. The scopes are permissions given to a user to do certain operations,for example there will be a scope for read a repository, another for update it, another one for delete etc..

These scopes are tied to the token and normally are requested by the user himself or added automatically depending on the user type. And the same as the authentication process, they could be included in the token itself coded as a claim in a jwt or they could be requested or checked by calling an oauth server when one operation is requested.

The advantages of include them in jwt is that there is not need to call an external server every time an operation is requested so there is a lower latency and less bandwith is required, also you remove a point of failure. Obviously if this solution is used the token must be properly signed or even encrypted to avoid possible manipulations.
However it has also drawbacks, and the most dangerous one is that the token cannot be revoked because this information cannot be included in the token and the service that check if the token is valid only can access the data contained in the token itself. Because of this, this kind of tokens are normally issued with a little expiry time so in case of the token is stolen, the validity of it will be very limited

Comment: So are you proposing that given a set of scopes a small structured key (but not JWT) is generated and based on the scopes given, is propagated out to the relevant services and only those services can authorize the key? I understand how JWTs are beneficial in most scenarios but I am interested in understanding how 3rd party tokens are actually authorized - which services they touch

Comment: No, if the scopes are encoded in the token as a claim inside a jwt then the service that recieves the token can check if that token is valid to perform the actions requested. If on the other hand the token is not a jwt (opaque token) then the service has to call the oauth server that has issued that token to check the scopes and with them ensure if the operation is authorized

Comment: Right, I understand the JWT portion, its much cleaner. But it sounds like with the API keys for 3rd party app access (such as Slack API or something similar) there's no way to avoid hitting the Auth service as they are opaque.